# JPQL: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am working with JPA and JPQL.  Using a JPQL I would like to fetch join a collection that is an attribute of a "main" entity rent. Here is my source code:

```
    public Rent getRentWithAllDetails(Rent rent) {

    Query queryString =  em.createQuery(" select r from Rent r JOIN FETCH r.rentables where r.id = :rid").setParameter(1, rent.getId());

    List <Rent> resultList = queryString.getResultList();

    return resultList.get(0);
}
```

and this is the exception I recieve:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.findParameterRegistration(BaseQueryImpl.java:518) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:674) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:198) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:49) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
```

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: understand the difference between JPA numbered (positional) and named parameters. There are many many documents on the internet telling you

Comment: @DN1, thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 3):

You are using a named parameter, so you should bind a parameter by that name while creating your query:

```
String sql = "select r from Rent r JOIN FETCH r.rentables where r.id = :rid";
Query queryString =  em.createQuery(sql)
    .setParameter("rid", rent.getId());
List<Rent> resultList = queryString.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code to:

```
public Rent getRentWithAllDetails(Rent rent) {
   Query queryString =  em.createQuery(" select r from Rent r JOIN FETCH r.rentables where r.id = :rid").setParameter("rid", rent.getId());
   List <Rent> resultList = queryString.getResultList();
   return resultList.get(0);
}
```

if `rid` is repeated multiple times, you can use 0,1..etc accordingly, otherwise use the parameter name itself.